# Bug in locate function?

Tags: triangulation, cgal, locate

I am a newer to CGAL, and when I use the .locate() function to locate
a point in a triangle, there are some problems. 
First I build a triangle with three point (-1,0) (1,0) (0,1),
Then I check some points' relative location with the triangle,
the points are:

> ```
> p0(0.8, 0.1) ---- locate in the triangle；
> p1(0.95, 0) ---- locate on the edge (-1,0) ---- (1,0)；
> p2(0.8, 0.2) ---- locate on the edge (1,0) ---- (0,1)；
> p3(0.6, 0.4) ---- locate on the edge (1,0) ---- (0,1)；
> p4(0.7,0.3) ---- locate on the edge (1,0) ---- (0,1)；
> ```

But the locate results are:

> ```
> p0 ---- FACE, right!
> p1 ---- EDGE, right!
> p2 ---- OUTSIDE_CONVEX_HULL, wrong!
> p3 ---- EDGE, right!
> p4 ---- FACE, wrong!
> ```

while the points p2, p3, p4 are locating on the same edge (1,0) ---- (0,1)

What's the reason for the problem?

The code:

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K> Delaunay_triangulation;

void main()
{
    //generate the triangles
    std::vector<Point2> pts;
    pts.push_back(Point2(1,0));
    pts.push_back(Point2(-1,0));
    pts.push_back(Point2(0,1));
    Delaunay_triangulation dt;
    dt.insert(pts.begin(), pts.end());

    //locate point in the triangle
    Point2 pt0 = Point2(0.8, 0.1);//the point located in the triangle.(on the FACE ?)
    Point2 pt1 = Point2(0.95, 0);//the point located on the segment ( (1,0) ---- (-1,0) ) (on the EDGE ?)
    Point2 pt2 = Point2(0.8, 0.2);//the point locate on the segment ( (1,0) ---- (0,1) ) (on the EDGE ?)
    Point2 pt3 = Point2(0.6, 0.4);//the point locate on the segment ( (1,0) ---- (0,1) ) (on the EDGE ?)
    Point2 pt4 = Point2(0.7,0.3);//the point locate on the segment ( (1,0) --- (0,1) ) (on the EDGE ?)
    Face_handle fh0, fh1, fh2, fh3, fh4;
    Delaunay_triangulation::Locate_type lt0, lt1, lt2, lt3, lt4;
    int li;
    fh0 = dt.locate(pt0, lt0, li);//for pt0, lt0 is equal to FACE, right!
    fh1 = dt.locate(pt1, lt1, li);//for pt1, lt1 is equal to EDGE, right!
    fh2 = dt.locate(pt2, lt2, li);//for pt2, lt2 is equal to OUTSIDE_CONVEX_HULL, I think it's wrong!
    fh3 = dt.locate(pt3, lt3, li);//for pt3, lt3 is equal to EDGE, right!
    fh4 = dt.locate(pt4, lt4, li);//for pt4, lt3 is equal to FACE, I thing it's wrong!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A floating point number cannot represent all decimal numbers one can write. There are rounding errors. For that reason, the coordinates of the points are not what you think. Take the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Point_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>

typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2 Point;

int main()
{
  std::cout.precision(17);
  Point p0(0.8, 0.1);
  Point p1(0.95, 0);
  Point p2(0.8, 0.2);
  Point p3(0.6, 0.4);
  Point p4(0.7,0.3);
  std::cout << p0 << std::endl;
  std::cout << p1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << p2 << std::endl;
  std::cout << p3 << std::endl;
  std::cout << p4 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It displays the coordinates of the points, with a high precision. The output is the following:

```
0.80000000000000004 0.10000000000000001
0.94999999999999996 0
0.80000000000000004 0.20000000000000001
0.59999999999999998 0.40000000000000002
0.69999999999999996 0.29999999999999999
```

Those coordinates explain all the locations returned by `locate()`.